# Could not load database driver: KylinEngineSpec

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, apache-superset, kylin

Just install Apache Superset within Kubernetes.
Already have a working Apache Kylin Cluster in the same Kubernetes Cluster.
While trying to connect Kylin within Superset i get the following error message:

> ERROR: Could not load database driver: KylinEngineSpec

Superset is installed using this repo:

```
helm repo add superset https://apache.github.io/superset
```

The connection string which is used:

```
kylin://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<project name>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify additional packages to install or did you install the chart with default values?

Comment: @p10l i used it with default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default superset comes with no `KylinEngineSpec` driver installed. You need to provide it as an additional requirement at install.

Recommended driver for Apache Kylin is `kylinpy` <sup>[[reference](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/installing-database-drivers#supported-databases-and-dependencies)]</sup>.

#### Update

The documentation is a bit misleading. Specifying additional packages in `additionalRequiremets` does not properly install them. Instead you have to add those to `bootstrapScript`.
Create a file with overrides (in my case it will be `my-values.yaml`),
add below to this file

```yaml
bootstrapScript: |
  #!/bin/bash
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  pip install \
    kylinpy \
    psycopg2==2.8.5 \
    redis==3.2.1 && \
  if [ ! -f ~/bootstrap ]; then echo "Running Superset with uid {{ .Values.runAsUser }}" > ~/bootstrap; fi
```

<sup>*Rembember, this will override `bootstrapScript` not add to it*</sup>
Then, to install superset with new values

```text
helm upgrade --install --values my-values.yaml <release-name> superset/superset
```

<sup>*Replace `<release-name>` witho your desired name*</sup>
or upgrade, if you already have superset installed

```text
helm upgrade --values my-values.yaml <release-name> superset/superset
```

<sup>*Again replace `<release-name>` with your release name*</sup>
Then, after execing into a pod, you can see `kylinpy` was installed

```text
root@superset-868c768599-24xc2:/app# pip list | grep kylinpy
kylinpy                2.8.4
```

---

To install it specify `additionalRequirements` with `--set` flag <sup>[[reference](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes#dependencies)]</sup>

```text
helm install --set additionalRequirements={kylinpy} <release-name> superset/superset
```

<sup>*replace `<release-name>` with your desired name*</sup>

If you already have superset installed, you can perform an upgrade:

```text
helm upgrade --set additionalRequirements={kylinpy} <release-name> superset/superset
```

<sup>*Again, replace `<release-name>` with your release name*</sup>

Use `helm get values` to see whether that new setting took effect. You should see something like

```text
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
additionalRequirements:
- kylinpy
```

---

I strongly recommend going through [official docs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes#running-on-kubernetes) about running superset in Kubernetes. There are a lot more settings to change other than database drivers.

Comment: I did this with the upgrade and set, I got the values but still the same issue, then i uninstalled it and installed it with the set and again I got the same issue, is something else that I need to do?

Comment: Exec into superset pod with `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash` and confirm `kylinpy` is installed with `pip list`

Comment: using the install with set, the kylinpy is not in the pip list, then I tried to install it with pip install inside the container then it was in the list but again is not working.

Comment: I also found this https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/apache/superset/14188/831992225 but i am unable to find bootstrap script in helm/superset folder

Comment: Updated my answer with proper installation instruction for `kylinpy`.  However I still can't pinpoint the cause of this error. Are you trying to connect from a script/program or a command line?